# Reducing Rows by Grouping Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of spreadsheets which define a set of business rules. These business rules are then processed by our system.

The users that create the spreadsheets do so naively and I have found that by factoring the data across rows - and thus reducing the number of rules - greatly improves performance of the system.

One of the "naively" structured spreadsheets might look like this:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| Rule Name | Criteron 1 | Criteron 2 | Criteron 3 | Criteron 4 | Accept |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| Rule 1    |      A     |      B     |      C     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 2    |      A     |      C     |      C     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 3    |      A     |      D     |      C     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 4    |      A     |      E     |      C     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 5    |      A     |      F     |      C     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 6    |      A     |      B     |      D     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 7    |      A     |      C     |      D     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 8    |      A     |      D     |      D     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 9    |      A     |      E     |      D     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 10   |      A     |      F     |      D     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 11   |      A     |      B     |      E     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 12   |      A     |      C     |      E     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 13   |      A     |      D     |      E     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 14   |      A     |      E     |      E     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 15   |      A     |      F     |      E     |            |  Yes   |
| Rule 16   |            |            |            |     G      |  Yes   |
| Rule 17   |            |            |            |     H      |  Yes   |
| Rule 18   |            |            |            |     I      |  Yes   |
| Rule 19   |            |            |            |     J      |  Yes   |
| Rule 20   |            |            |            |     K      |  Yes   |
| Rule 21   |            |            |            |     L      |  Yes   |
| Rule 22   |            |            |            |     M      |  Yes   |
| Rule 23   |            |            |            |     N      |  No    |
| Rule 24   |            |            |            |     O      |  No    |
| Rule 25   |            |            |            |     P      |  No    |
| Rule 26   |            |            |            |     Q      |  No    |
| Rule 27   |            |            |            |     R      |  No    |
| Rule 28   |            |            |            |     S      |  No    |
| Rule 29   |      A     |      J     |      F     |            |  No    |
| Rule 30   |      A     |      K     |      F     |            |  No    |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

As an example, Rule 1 would be evaluated as:

```
IF (Criterion 1 == A) AND (Criterion 2 == B) AND (Criterion 3 == C) THEN Accept
```

Using a bit of thought and assuming we can use OR conditionals in our columns, the above can be reduced to:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+--------+
| Rule Name | Criteron 1 | Criteron 2 | Criteron 3 | Criteron 4  | Accept |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+--------+
| Rule 1    |      A     |  B,C,D,E,F |    C,D,E   |             |  Yes   |
| Rule 2    |            |            |            |G,H,I,J,K,L,M|  Yes   |
| Rule 3    |            |            |            |N,O,P,Q,R,S  |  No    |
| Rule 4    |      A     |     J,K    |      F     |             |  No    |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+--------+
```

Rule 1 is now evaluated as follows:

```
IF (Criterion 1 == A) AND 
   (Criterion 2 == B OR Criterion 2 == C OR...) AND 
   (Criterion 3 == C OR Criterion 3 == D OR...) THEN Accept
```

Now, I've done this manually. What I want to know is: does Excel have in-built functionality to do this kind of grouping for me. If not, can anyone point me in the direction of an algorithm which will help me implement this efficiently?

Comment: You may have to better describe the logic you use that combines Rules 1 thru 15 in to Rule 1 in your reduced output, because I don't follow why those 15 "Rules" all reduce to one rule in your output. If you can do that, this could most certainly be done with some VBA.

Comment: please show us the rules/criteria you are using

Comment: @DavidZemens, I've added to my question - hopefully this is more clear now.

Comment: @Philip I'm not able to give you the real rules I am using. Even if I was, they would be just as abstract to you.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a situation where you could query the table using ADO and OLE DB into an ADO Recordset using GROUP BY HAVING in the SQL Query, then dump the (grouped) results into your new sheet using **CopyFromRecordset**

Alternatively, perhaps a Pivot Table?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Philip, would you please give some more details on your solution?

Comment: well, if you turn your table into a Named Range (such as 'RulesData' then save the workbook and close it. Open a new workbook, and on the Data menu select > Import External Data > New Database Query..., and (initially) create a dsn connection for your Excel file, and in MS Query, create a SQL Query to select the data from the table 'RulesData' and group it (using GROUP BY)